# Comparar una variable javascript con otra variable que contiene registros de una tabla de mi base de datos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

Tengo un input en mi vista blade donde selecciono una fecha cualquiera.

y tengo otro input en la misma vista blade donde llamo los registros de mi base de datos.

y por ultimo tengo este script donde comparo la variable del input que tiene el id="fecha1"con la variable del input que tiene el id="fecha2" este segundo input me permite cargar los registros de mi base de datos. pero al ejecutar solo me compara el primer registro de la base y yo quiero que la comparación la haga con todos los registros de la columna "dia_festivo". Para que en caso de coincidir la fecha_1 con la fecha_2 se muestre un alert, de lo contrario permita agregar una fecha exitosamente.

Gracias y saludos

```js
<script>
fecha_1=$("#fecha1").val();
var fecha_2= document.getElementById("fecha2").value;
    if( fecha_1!=fecha_2)
    { 
       alert("Fecha agregada correctamente");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("No puedes seleccionar días festivos ");
    }
</script>
```

```html
    <input type ="date" id="fecha1">
@foreach($festivos as $festivo)
    <input type="hidden" id="fecha2" 
        value="{{$festivo->dia_festivo}}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: Para realizar lo que necesitas debes obtener los registros de tu **BD** y recorrerla con un _loop_ en tu código. Ahora lo único que estas haciendo es obtener los valores de los `input` y comparar si son iguales o no, no estas recorriendo nada =|

Comment: Pense que que con el foreach recorría los registros, o crees que tenga que hacerlo en mi script,  pero no estoy seguro de como hacerlo, ayuda porfavor

Comment: Saludos Armando, bienvenido a SOes, un dato de vital importancia: escribir en mayúsculas = gritar, edita el título y el contenido por favor. Gracias

Comment: @Armando para entender mejor.. lo que quieres es realizar una búsqueda por fechas? entregando una fecha de inicio y fecha fin y que la **BD** te devuelvo los registros comprendidos entre esas fechas?

Comment: En resumen lo que busco es saber como guardar datos de un foreach declarado con blade,  en un array de Javascript,